# How to post data to elastic search over java?

Tags: java, json, maven, elasticsearch, build-dependencies

How to post data to elasticsearch from java application?
What are the necessary Maven dependencies to make queries to elastic search engine?

I have done a lot of research but got confused.

Thanks in Advance !!!!!

Comment: This question doesn't really make a lot of sense. Maven is a build tool. Are you asking how to build a small client to post data to elastic search and then run said client with Maven?

Comment: Yes, I am asking how to build a small client to post data to elastic search over java .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Elasticsearch will be enough (look for the latest version in **maven repository** https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch) :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In addition, if you are familiar with **scala** (in java these operations are pretty much the same), you can use this **XContentBuilder** example to create json objects: https://github.com/sslavian812/needls2/blob/master/src/main/scala/ru/yandex/spark/ElasticSearchHelper.scala#L42

and this **elasticsearch client** request example: https://github.com/sslavian812/needls2/blob/master/src/main/scala/ru/yandex/spark/ElasticSearchHelper.scala#L125

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

- Clone elasticsearch's maven dependency (from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch))
- Use Transport Client or Node Client to connect to Elasticsearch ([here's](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_transport_client_versus_node_client.html) the documentation that explains both the types and [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-java-clients-for-elasticsearch) are the examples)
- Use `IndexRequest` to index the document, e.g.:

  `IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest("<index_name>","<document_type>", "<document_id>");
  request.source("<document_json>");
  IndexResponse response = client.index(indexRequest).actionGet();`

Comment: thanks its a great help. But how to code a post request in java ?

Comment: `client.index(indexRequest).actionGet()` would do that for you